# Android ViewPager setCurrentItem not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

I'm having trouble implementing setCurrentItem on my viewpager.

I am attempting to save the integer in shared pref, so when the user comes back to the activity, its at the same page they left off at.

Here is my activity with the viewpager:

```
public class MyWorkout extends BaseActivity {

NonSwipeableViewPager vp;
TextView txtViewTitle;
String workoutTitle;
SharedPreferences pref;
private final String LOG = MyWorkout.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
    int currentPage = pref.getInt("currentPage", 0);


    setContentView(R.layout.my_workout);

    mToolBar = activateToolbar();
    setUpNavigationDrawer();
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("My Workout");


    workoutTitle = pref.getString("current_workout", "default");
    Button btnPrev = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPrevious);
    Button btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
    vp = (NonSwipeableViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    txtViewTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtViewTitle);
    this.addPages(vp);

    vp.setCurrentItem(currentPage);
    Log.d(LOG, "current value is " + currentPage);

    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MoveNext();
        }
    });

    btnPrev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            MovePrevious();
        }
    });


    public void MoveNext() {
    vp.setCurrentItem(vp.getCurrentItem() + 1);
    int current = vp.getCurrentItem();
    pref.edit().putInt("currentPage", current).apply();
    Log.d(LOG, "current value is " + current);
}

public void MovePrevious() {
    vp.setCurrentItem(vp.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    int current = vp.getCurrentItem();
    pref.edit().putInt("currentPage", current).apply();
    Log.d(LOG, "current value is " + current);
}
```

I know it is properly adding/subtracting to the shared pref based on the log. When I click next, it adds one, when I hit previous, it subtracts one. The problem must be with the line:

```
vp.setCurrentItem(currentPage);
```

When I go back to the page, it always goes back to the first page.

Here is my NonSwipeableViewPager:

```
public class NonSwipeableViewPager extends ViewPager {

public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setMyScroller();
}

public NonSwipeableViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setMyScroller();
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // Never allow swiping to switch between pages
    return false;
}

//down one is added for smooth scrolling

private void setMyScroller() {
    try {
        Class<?> viewpager = ViewPager.class;
        Field scroller = viewpager.getDeclaredField("mScroller");
        scroller.setAccessible(true);
        scroller.set(this, new MyScroller(getContext()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public int getCurrentItem() {
    return super.getCurrentItem();
}

@Override
public void setCurrentItem(int item) {
    super.setCurrentItem(item);
}

public class MyScroller extends Scroller {
    public MyScroller(Context context) {
        super(context, new DecelerateInterpolator());
    }

    @Override
    public void startScroll(int startX, int startY, int dx, int dy, int duration) {
        super.startScroll(startX, startY, dx, dy, 350 /*1 secs*/);
    }
}
}
```

And here is MyFragPagerAdapter:

```
public class MyFragPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

ArrayList<Fragment> pages = new ArrayList<>();


public MyFragPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
    super(fm);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return pages.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return pages.size();
}

//ADD A PAGE

public void addPage(Fragment f) {
    pages.add(f);
}
}
```

I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing, but maybe a fresh pair of eyes will help! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The moveNext() and moveBack() methods are working because you seem to be pulling the index from the view pager, rather than from the shared preferences. I would print out the value in the shared preferences, by retrieving it, every time you save it and make sure it's right. It looks like it's defaulting to 0--the first index--so maybe it's not being stored correctly. Try calling apply() in a separate line.

Comment: Thanks for response. I think the shared prefs is working fine, because even the log right after setCurrentItem is giving me the proper value. I also tried set current page to just 5 to see if it would work, unfortunately it didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the index of current page after setting the current item.

so there is no need to calculate the index.

you should directly save the value of `vp.getCurrentItem().`

Comment: You're right I had a lot of redundant code! I changed the code in my first post, unfortunately it still does not work. It is saving properly in shared pref I believe, but it is not setting the correct page. Even if I change it to vp.setCurrentPage(5), it still stays on page 1.

Comment: can you try with the normal **ViewPager**, not **NonSwipeableViewPager**? then it works or not? then we can be sure that NonSwipeableViewPager is exactly ok or not.

Answer (score 0):

My case is a bit different, but I'll include my solution to help anyone that may be having the same issue.

`setCurrentItem()` wasn't working for me because **I'd forgotten to update `getCount()`**.

My `getCount()` method in my implementation of the `FragmentPagerAdapter` was displaying the incorrect count, so it could not change page since it was not part of its count.